# Py4j Cannot connect to Java Server

Tags: python, py4j

I was trying to write a simple program to setup a connection between python and java using py4j. I wrote the following two lines hoping that everything would run since I'm not making any changes

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway, GatewayParameters
gateway = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=25335))
random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()
```

which resulted in the following error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:25335)

I looked around for a while and read that this might happen if java is listening on to a different port. So I wrote a for block to see what happens

```
for i in range(65535+1):
    try:
        gateway = JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=i))
        random = gateway.jvm.java.util.Random()
        print("passed port num", str(i))
    except:
        pass
```

The above block yielded nothing. None of the ports could connect. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

How do I find the port number which the java side is using?

I am using py4j version 0.10.7 and python 3.6.0

**EDIT**

I have used the same java code as used in the [py4j tutorial](https://www.py4j.org/getting_started.html)

I have a file called `java_stack.java` and `py4j_gs.java`. Both are in the same directory. I'm calling  `java py4j_gs.java from the terminal. These are the contents of the two files

**java_stack.java**

```
package py4j.examples;    
import py4j.GatewayServer;
public class StackEntryPoint {
    private Stack stack;
    public StackEntryPoint() {
      stack = new Stack();
      stack.push("Initial Item");
    }
    public Stack getStack() {
        return stack;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new StackEntryPoint());
        gatewayServer.start();
        System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
    }    
}
```

**py4j_gs.java**

```
package py4j.examples;
import py4j.GatewayServer;
public class StackEntryPoint {
    private Stack stack;
    public StackEntryPoint() {
      stack = new Stack();
      stack.push("Initial Item");
    }
    public Stack getStack() {
        return stack;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new StackEntryPoint());
        gatewayServer.start();
        System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Java side of it? Is it running?

Comment: @VikrantSharma, I missed the part where I need to run scripts from the java side. I have done that now looking at the tutorial linked.  However,  I now get  `Error: Could not find or load main class py4j_gs.java`. 

PS: I have never coded in java so I am not even sure if my java programs are correct.

Comment: I suggest you create a virtualenv and install py4j in that environment, if you haven't already.

Comment: You'll need to compile and run the Java program with something like `javac -cp .env/share/py4j/py4j0.10.7.jar:. YourProgram.java`

Comment: Java source files must be named after the class names, so your filenames should be StackEntryPoint.java

Comment: @VikrantSharma, Thanks for the help. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced something same like

> py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server

while working on pyspark shell.
 To solve this first we need to start the java geteway server.
**After executing following java code my problem got resolve.**

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test app = new Test ();
        // app is now the gateway.entry_point
        GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(app);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: To put it more precisely, the java code is written in the java project, and the python code is written in the Python project. Thus, we first execute the java code, for example, within Eclipse, then execute the python code, for example, within the Spyder or directly "python3 ./xx.py" from the terminal